# How to parse an array of objects with JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

JQuery isn't my strong point, but this seems very straightforward but cannot seem to parse these objects. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

I have an array that looks like this:

```
{"occupation": "Boxer", "id": 2},{"occupation": "Helper", "id": 3}
```

My end result needs to look like this: (an array of ids):

```
[ 2, 3 ]
```

I have tried using `$.each` to iterate over the `data.occupations` array but I get a TypeError. Can someone tell me *why* this isn't working?

Here is the loop I'm using:

```
$.each(data.occupations, function (name, value) {
  console.log(name);
});
```

**EDIT:**

This is what is shown to me in the Inspector:

```
Object {
  name: "Alex Barma",
  occupations: "{"occupation": "Boxer", "occup…", 6 more…
}
```

I just noticed that `occupations` isn't an array. Would I need to create an array and push the objects into it before I can loop over them?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring an empty array and using `$.each` to inject items, simply use jQuery's `$.map` function instead, e.g.

```
var ids = $.map(data.occupations, function(o) {
    return o.id;
});
```

Of course, this is assuming that **occupations** is a key that stores the array in your `data` object.

See proof-of-concept code below:

```js
$(function() {
  var data = {
    occupations: [{
        "occupation": "Boxer",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "occupation": "Helper",
        "id": 3
      }
    ]
  };

  var ids = $.map(data.occupations, function(o) {
    return o.id;
  });
  
  console.log(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is what the log shows me. Occupations is a key, so map would work for me here? `Object {
  name: "Alex Barma",
  occupations: "{"occupation": "Actor", "occupation"...
}`

Comment: using your example gives me `TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a`

Comment: I don't understand it, your example is about as straightforward and simple as it gets, yet, it won't work.

Comment: I just noticed that the `occupations` key in the `data` object is not an array, but rather objects. Do I need to create an array and push the objects into it first?

Comment: @NaN Show us your full data structure. You’ve only showed a subset of your data so we don’t really know how to traverse/access the array.

Comment: OK, I'll post up top.